# vscodeで自動補完機能のつけ方を教えて欲しいです。

Tags: vscode

タイトルの通りです。

最近ATOMからVScodeに変更したのですが、自動補完機能のやり方がわかりません。

ATOMだったら、例えば、divなどを打った後にTABキーを打つと`<div></div>`のようになりますが、VScodeで同じようなやり方が、調べましたがわからないので、教えていただきたいです。

MACを使ってます。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: VSCode自身のDocsの中に、英語ですが細かい機能と対応する設定や拡張機能について記述されています。[HTML in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html), [CSS, SCSS and Less](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css), [Emmet in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet), [Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_settings) 他に日本語記事とか。[【今日から携わる】はじめてのVisual Studio Code入門（オススメの設定・プラグイン・使い方）](https://qiita.com/abeno/items/6366bfe1ea8e5f6ee07c)

Answer (score 1):

VS Code では多くのプログラミング言語に対して拡張機能によって自動補完を実装しており、どの言語のモードを使っているかによって自動補完のやり方や必要な拡張機能が異なります。また、いくつかの言語ではデフォルトで対応されています。

質問文に書かれている HTML に関しては、公式ドキュメントが存在します：

- [HTML in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html)

ここに書かれているとおり、デフォルト設定では `</` を打ったときに閉じタグが補完されます。また <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> を押すと手動で補完を呼び出せます。